# I am not able to populate new data into my database using dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to learn CRUD using dot net. Other functions such as delete works just fine but whenever I try to insert new data, it does not populate in the database and shows no errors either. The controller is as follows:

```
    private readonly IRepository<Category> _categoriesRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<Model> _modelsRepository;

    public CategoriesController(IRepository<Category> categoriesRepository, IRepository<Model> modelsRepository)
    {
        _categoriesRepository = categoriesRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(categoriesRepository));
        _modelsRepository = modelsRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelsRepository));
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Categories/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind("CategoryID,CategoryName")] Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _categoriesRepository.Create(category);
            _categoriesRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(category);
    }
```

repository:

```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public CategoriesRepository(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext(options);
    }

    public void Create(Category category)
    {
        db.Categories.Add(category);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

What is wrong here? and How can I fix it?

Comment: first, check what you receiving inside create() method  of repository. If value are valid then try db.savechanges() below db.Categories.Add(category);

Comment: You should first check whether the ModelState.IsValid statement is true or false by adding a breakpoints in the code. I think that the issue is not with the CRUD operation itself, but rather with the invalid model being passed.

Comment: Thank You. Seems like the issue was in the declaration of columns in Category.cs. A column was being passed as null when it didn't accept null value. Thus creating a ModelState.IsValid as False.

Comment: How's your Category class can you share your full class along with dbContext defination?